# How to convert an array to string with index

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, indexing

I would like to convert an Array like this:

```
 array ( [1_1] => 1 [1_2] => 2 [1_3] => 3 [1_4] => 4 [1_5] => 5 )
```

to an string like this:

```
"1_1-1/1_2-2/1_3-3/1_4-4/1_5-5"
```

how can I do it?

I need the Index and the values in my MySQL-Databse.

I tryed implode() but this is the result:

```
1/2/3/4/5
```

thank you

Comment: You can loop and build your own string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$out = "";
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    $out .= "$k-$v/";
}
$out = substr($out, 0, -1); //this line will remove the extra '/'
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP < 5.5**

It's better to store all these values in an associative array and then implode them

```
$final = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
    $final[] = $key.'-'.$val;
}
$final = implode('/', $final);
```

**PHP = 5.5**

You may want to use generators to yeld these values assuming they are regular:
See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use http_build_query() to do that.

http://www.php.net/http_build_query

Try:

```
     echo http_build_query($array, '', '/');
```